# Is it possible to have a VLC skin with all the options of the native style?

Tags: vlc-media-player

The VLC native style has a lot of options, both in the main menus and in the playlist

[image]

Most of these are lost when using a [custom skin](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php).

After searching for [a skin that would keep all the native style options](https://askubuntu.com/q/136563/47206), without success, I wander if this is really possible.

Comment: It is possible. However, this decision of including the menus is up to the creator of the skin.

Comment: @matan129 - that seems probable (until seeing that out of hundred of skins **none** does that)

Comment: Yeah, I think like you, it's odd. But [possible](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins2-create.html) (hit Ctrl+f and search for "menu")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [possible](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins2-create.html) to have a VLC skin with menus.
However, the decision of including these menus is up to the skin developer.

Quoting from the document:

- > dialogs.popup(): Show the full popup menu.
- > dialogs.audioPopup(): Show the audio settings popup menu (since VLC 0.8.6).

And so on.

Comment: a great answer (and question) would be - "how to modify a skin and add all the options". i cannot create one but how hard can it be just to add that popup menu? (and is "full popup menu" all the menus as described in the question or just the right-click context menu?)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken every menu (drop-down) has it's own function which makes it appear. 
Try downloading a skin from and edition its files, the way you would normally do if you started a skin.

Comment: with the skin editor i am able to extract a skin, but i cannot myself edit the 'theme.xml' file which is the thing to do :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that without the XML file you won't be able to fix this.. 
So I guess that the final answer to your question is: "It is possible, up to the developer and you can't change that". :(

Comment: i'll try entering in contact with a skin developer